# edit profile validation refreshes all field if missing wordpress

Tags: users, validation

In the edit profile section whenever I'm updating a field and if for example I've missed one required field (NickName) and changed the email address to a new one, the WordPress validation will refreshes all field and the new email address that I've entered would be lost.

I'm not using any third party plugin to edit profile only the generic WP one. 
This is the user edit page https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/user-edit.php

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want. You mean if you change some informations and when you click to save, if occur some error you don't want to lose all the informations previously added?

Comment: yes so basically if I filled in the form (empty form for example) and I missed a field and click on submit everything gets removed (because it was empty in the first place) and I have to fill back the form again.

Comment: This could be seen as a bug or an improvement with WP itself so you might consider filing an issue on trac: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-bugs/

Comment: @kraftner I did [file an issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41314) with a link to this question. The answer was :  `This could be as simple as using the validateForm() JavaScript function available in WordPress.`

Comment: Look forward to your core patch @JackJohansson

Comment: @birgire Instead of doing this via a wall of jQuery code, can't this simply be done by adding `required` to email and nickname input fields?

Comment: Sounds logical but not sure how that plays with WP localization, browser support and native WP admin notice style @JackJohansson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Approach 1, disable save button

What you can do, is to prevent the user from saving the form if the required fields are not filled. This can be simply done via javascript.

```
function require_fields_script(){
    echo "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            (function($){
                $('#submit').on('click',function(e){
                    if (!$('#email').val() || !$('#nickname').val()){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (!$('#email').val()) {
                            window.alert('Please enter your email before saving.');
                        } else {
                            window.alert('Please enter your nickname before saving.');
                        }
                    }
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>";
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'require_fields_script' );
```

This can also be done by saving the values in a transient/globals and retrieving them after a fail save, but that's not necessary.

The point is, if the field is not set, there is no reason to let the user save it at the first place.

### Approach 2, revert to default values

There is also another trick. When you load the page, there will be some default/pre-saved value as email and nickname. If the user tried to save the form without entering these, you can set them back to the old values. To do so, this is your way:

```
function require_fields_script(){
    echo "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            (function($){
                var currentMail = $('#email').val();
                var currentNickname = $('#nickname').val();
                $('#submit').on('click',function(e){
                    if (!$('#email').val()){
                        $('#email').val(currentMail);
                    }
                    if (!$('#nickname').val()){
                        $('#nickname').val(currentNickname);
                    }
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>";
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'require_fields_script' );
```

### Approach 3, fake an admin alert using jQuery

We can create a fake admin error by using `$.before` if the fields are not set. This is how we do it:

```
function require_fields_script(){
    echo "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            (function($){
                $('#submit').on('click',function(e){
                    if (!$('#email').val()){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $( '#your-profile' ).before( '<div class=\'error\'><p><strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter an email.</p><button type=\'button\' class=\'notice-dismiss\'><span class=\'screen-reader-text\'>Dismiss this notice.</span></button></div>' );
                        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},700);
                    }
                    if (!$('#nickname').val()){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $( '#your-profile' ).before( '<div class=\'error\'><p><strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter a nickname.</p><button type=\'button\' class=\'notice-dismiss\'><span class=\'screen-reader-text\'>Dismiss this notice.</span></button></div>' );
                        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},700);
                    }
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>";
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'require_fields_script' );
```

This will throw an error and scroll the page to top, so the user can be noticed of the error. We can remove the `div` afterward, but since it will be removed automatically on save, it's not really necessary to do. Anyway, to remove the errors, you can use `$.remove()`:

```
if ($('.error').length) {
    $('.error').remove();
}
```

### PATCH UPDATE

I've created a patch that fully resolves the issue by doing AJAX and jQuery checks. The patch can be found on trac [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41314). At the moment it has a minor bug, which I'll cover it that soon.

Comment: Looks like it's going to work. I have to run some more test on it (I have some custom fields. Also, rather than the pop up can it shows which textbox is missing?

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar I tested both of them before posting. It can be customized since it's flexible. Do you want to show exactly if the email is missing or the nickname?

Comment: Approach 1 makes the most sense, IMO. As you put it, _The point is, if the field is not set, there is no reason to let the user save it at the first place_.  It's odd to me the save action is available when required form fields are missing.

Comment: yes I would love to show exactly. Im working with about 20 custom fields and so far everything is working! Thanks!! But I would love for the user to know which one is missing rather than nickname/Official title/position/etc. is missing

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar I've updated the first code. It does what you are asking now.

Comment: @hwl It's rather strange, yes. It should actually disable the submit button and show an alert.

Comment: it does works thanks again! but as I said earlier what if you have about 20 fields? Should I just put a bunch of if else statement?

Comment: Surrounding form field(s) in red border to highlight what's missing is another common addition. Regardless, some version of your solution may be a solid core improvement as Kraftner noted in his comment above.

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar Yes you can, you just have to repeat the pattern and add `elseif()` for the rest of your fields. Also check the 3rd solution I just added. It's almost as real as a real admin error.

Comment: Can the previous error be removed when the user resubmitted? Because if there's another error, it'll keep building up and it'll show duplicate error messages. Thanks

Comment: @ParbhuBissessar Yes it can. I've added the way to remove the errors. Include the added code in `$('#submit').on('click',function(e){ ... });` and before printing the new error (first line maybe).